# Props not passing can someone check it

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, tsx

> Blockquote

Unable to pass props,

```
Parent component:
props: {
    data: {
      type: Object as PropType<FormatOrderItem>,
      default: () => {}
    }
```

Now, when in child component I try to pass I get type Error could you help me fix this,

```
  <ElScrollbar>
    {Store.Record.map((item, index) => (
  <ResultItem status={form.status} key={index + '_KEY'} data={item} />
  ))}
  </ElScrollbar>
```

Error received at data={item}

> TS2322: Type '{ status: 0 | 2 | 1 | null | undefined; key: string;
> value: { id: string; username: string; leagueId: number; leagueName:
> string; homeId: number; awayId: number; matchTime: number; sportType:
> number; ... 41 more ...; versionKey: string; }; }' is not assignable
> to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Partial<{ data: FormatOrderItem; }> &
> Omit<Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<{ data: { type:
> PropType; default: () => {}; }; status: { ...; }; }>>
> & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, "data">'.
> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> Partial<{ data: FormatOrderItem; }> & Omit<Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<{
> data: { type: PropType; default: () => {}; }; status:
> { ...; }; }>> & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps &
> ComponentCustomProps, "data">'.

```
<ElScrollbar>
{Store.Record.map((item, index) => (`enter code here`
<ResultItem status={form.status} key={index + '_KEY'} data={item} />
))}
</ElScrollbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed now. I used

```
props: {
    data: {
      type: Object as PropType<any>,
      default: () => {}
    }
}
```